# ArrayList [] set = new ArrayList[n];

Tags: arraylist

What is this ??

ArrayList [] set = new ArrayList[n];

Implementation of arraylist is:

ArrayList Integer>  al  = new ArrayList Integer> ();

Answer (score 3):

The first what you had defined

```
ArrayList [] set = new ArrayList[n];
```

This is an array of ArrayList. As we know that ArrayList is a class. So the first statement defines the array of ArrayList class.

The second example is

```
ArrayList Integer> al = new ArrayList Integer> ();
```

Here you are creating the object of ArrayList. So here you are creating an object of ArrayList class and will be adding values in it.

Below is an example that contains the use of both

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList[] set = new ArrayList[10];
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("RHV");
        list.add("Zen");

        set[0] = list;

        System.out.println(set[0]);
    }
}
```